# Magento 2 variable @mobile-cart-padding is undefined (Porto Theme)

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, deploy, undefined-variable

I Cloned Magento 2 project from GitHub without any error. After I configured env files with DB details. when I deploy the project getting variable @mobile-cart-padding is an undefined error. I am using the Porto theme. In the Porto theme, I got an error The contents from the `/home/server/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/styles-l.css` file can't be read.

> Warning!file_get_contents(/home/server/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/sty
>   les-l.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@mobile-cart-padding: 15px;` at the top of a
`/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/css/source/_extends.less` file.